# entity framework core. ASP.NET Core

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Есть ли метод, который возвращает последующие 10 записей. Например нужно сделать пагинацию. Есть ID записи после которой мне нужно вернуть следующии 10 записей. Что б не писать в ручную этот костыль может есть что-то адекватное, куда передаешь ид и на выходе получаешь след 10 записей после него. Спасибо

Comment: Есть Skip и Take, они точно нормально транслируются в sql

Comment: ну обычно при пагинации использую номер страницы и кол-во записей на тсранице и по ним вычисляют а не по индексам сущностей

Answer (score 1):

```
var indexSkip = allElements.FindIndex(e => e.Id == id) + 1;


return allElements.Skip(indexSkip).Take(20);
```

Comment: allElements я так понимаю уже готовый List всех записей?

Comment: @FX_Sektor - Ни в коем случае не `List`! Это должна быть таблица (`DbSet`/`IQueryable`) EntifyFramework. Вы же не хотите _все_ данные вытянуть разом из БД на клиента.

Comment: И, кстати, обязательно нужна сортировка. Иначе результаты непредсказуемы.